# ruby connect SQL server by using Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, ruby

I referred this  page

http://www.codecapers.com/post/using-ruby-with-sql-server.aspx

my code

```
  DBI.connect('DBI:ADO:Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=SQLSERVER001;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=DB001') do | dbh |
     # Replace mytable with the name of a table in your database.
     dbh.select_all('select top 1000 * from history where type="35"  ') do | row |
        puts row
     end
  end
```

and trying to connect ruby with sql server by Windows authentication . But I got error

Unable to load driver 'ADO' (underlying error: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::ADO)

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://gordonotspanish.blogspot.com/2010/02/resolved-uninitialized-constant.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't need TinyTds, my system: ruby 1.9.3, ruby [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/), sql server 2012, windows 7

install these gems first;

```
gem install dbi
gem install dbd-odbc
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
```

working script below connects, (not sure about the require 'pp')

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'DBI'
require 'pp'

server = 'XXXXX-LT0XXXX\XXX'

database = 'mydatabase'

conn = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=#{server};Database=#{database};Trusted_Connection=yes") #==> sets up the connection

puts conn.connected?
```

if you pass the sql server instance directly into the connection string with a backslash it error but if passed as a variable it accepts

Answer (score -1):

The page you are refering to is three years old.

Today you should use TinyTds for an easy way accessing
A MS SqlServer ( look at Github for it )

Comment: thanks, I looked through there two git repo  https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter   https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds I still didn't see an example hot to connect SQL Server with trusted connecton. Could you point an example please?

Comment: Oh sry, TinyTds currently does not support Windows authentication